# double integral over 2 circles with 1 common point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the value of the integral $\int\int \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ over region $D={(x,y): x\le x^2+y^2 \le 2x}$.

after drawing a sketch of the region.and converting x and y into polar co-ortdinates
$x= r\cos\theta$,$y=r\sin\theta$.The region became
$\cos\theta\le r$$ \le 2\cos\theta$.
 $-\pi/2\le \theta\le\pi/2$. after integration the value became $28/9$.
i dont know if its correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Your integral will be
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{\cos\theta}^{2\cos\theta}r\cdot rdrd\theta=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac 13(2\cos\theta)^3-\frac 13\cos^3\theta\right)d\theta$$
$$=\frac 73\left(\frac{3\sin\theta}{4}+\frac{\sin(3\theta)}{12}\right)\large|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}=\frac{28}{9}.$$

Comment: how are u determining the theta?? by drawing the diagram or can u arrive at it by the equations only??

Comment: the equations only. I think you've already written it...

Comment: @Prayagdeep: oh, you are asking if $-\pi/2\le \theta \pi/2$ is correct? I think $0\le \theta\le \pi/2$ is better. We usually use this.